# SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error when copying database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, copy

The code for copying database:

```
        public static final String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/MyPackageName/databases/";
        public static final String DB_NAME = "MyDB.sqlite";
        private void copyDataBase(String dbPath){
            try{

                InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(dbName);

                OutputStream appDB = new FileOutputStream(dbPath,false);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    appDB.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                appDB.flush();
                appDB.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

this code is work fine in every phone and every android version, but i get a SQLiteDiskIOException in some phones (for example Galaxy S Plus) in above code or this line:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = super.getWritableDatabase();
```

everyone can help me in this problem?

Comment: Please use `getDatabasePath()` instead of your current code for `DB_PATH`. Also, please consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper` rather than rolling your own: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks my friend,
my problem is solved with using SQLiteAssetHelper introduced in https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper